# Tauri custom titlebar with native buttons

Tags: next.js, tauri

I just started playing with Tauri, and I am trying to find something that does not state in the documentation.

I deactivated the default titlebar, to use my own custom titlebar, but there is something that I am not managing to get. I want to have a title bar, with the default browser buttons + some menu buttons from my side, but I don't seem to see how to import the default OS buttons to close, maximise and minimise. I would love to create both for windows and osx.

Can someone guide me through it?

I am using tauri (rust + NextJS(static)) combo

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible code sample.